# How do I remove the normalizations from sql?

Tags: mysql, nosql

I am trying to migrate from mysql to nosql and I need to remove normalizations. Is this necessary?, If not how do I approach this.

Comment: you can use normalization and if nosql like mongo you can store all data in same table also

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just export tables as CSV files (or JSON or XML) an then import into Mongo?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/
https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mongodb

MySQL workbench can export in JSON format.

MongoDB is the only NoSQL database that combines the best features of relational databases along with the innovations of NoSQL.